# VBA Scraping a website (with javascript?)

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I'm trying to pull data from tab.com.au through VBA. I can't figure out how to update the site when I change the value of the dropdown list. The dropdown, in my novice opinion, doesn't seem to have an element ID.

The site is tab.com.au. When you click the Menu on the upper left, a navigation pane becomes visible. At the bottom of that navigation pane is the dropdown that has values either ACT, NSW, or VIC. If you manually change the value of the dropdown, the site reloads contents referencing to the newly selected value.

To provide a little background of the site, it contains racing information where 3 different pools are sharing the same page but with differenct values (pools are the 3 states they covered (dropdown items)). If you change the dropdown value, race information like prices, ratings, etc. will change.

here is my code ---

```
Sub changejuris()

 Dim iE As InternetExplorer: Set iE = New InternetExplorer

 iE.Visible = True

iE.Navigate "https://www.tab.com.au/racing/2015-10-26/COONABARABRAN/CBR/R/1"

'please change the url to current day racing
'note that url above becomes not available a day after the race
'they move data to their previous site daily so today's data can not be loaded tomorrow using the same url.

While (iE.Busy Or iE.readyState <> 4)

 Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

 Wend

 Dim cls As IHTMLElementCollection

 Set cls = iE.document.getElementsByClassName("common-dropdown")

'sometimes this becomes "common-dropdown jurisdiction-vic"
 'or "common-dropdown jurisdiction-act"
 'depending on current selected jurisdiction

cls(0).Children(0).Focus

cls(0).Children(0).Value = "string:vic"

cls(0).Children(0).Click

 iE.Quit

 Set iE = Nothing

 End Sub
```